# How to call a function after it's already defined in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a function that grabs text data from [this site](http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/) and stores it in a JSON file. This function is only crawling the first page of this website, but I'd like click through or "goto" each url (there are 10 pages) and grab the text data from each page:

```
    await page.goto('http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/')

    //grab quote data
    const quotes = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const grabFromDiv = (div, selector) => Array.from(div 
        .querySelectorAll(selector), (el => el.innerText.trim()))
```

Currently, it just navigates to page 1, grabs the data, stores it, and then exits. Is there a way to call the quotes function over and over until I've navigated through all 10 pages and collected all the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the same for each page.

If you know the number of pages, then just do:

```
var quotes = '' 
for each page
    await page.goto(page)
    quotes+ = await page.evaluate(myPageFunction)
```

If you don't know the number of pages, you need to get that information from the actual page.

then, in the evaluate function just search for the next page:

```
myPageFunction = function(){
    // get your data
    const nextPage = document.querySelector('.next a')?.href
    return {data: yourData, nextPage: nextPage}
}
```

You would then have something like:

```
nextPage = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
while (nextPage= {
    await page.goto(nextPage)
    const result = await page.evaluate(myPageFunction)
    quotes += result.data
    nextPage = resut.nextPage
}
```

The code is just an example and won't work as is.

Best!